# MyProfilePage where it is linked?

Tags: apex

I have a page in sandbox same like the below, Its created 2013. Now i try to find out where its linked. I checked the dependencies but nothing found. Just curious to know where it may used ?

[Page look like this](https://github.com/companieshouse/forms-enablement-salesforce/blob/master/src/pages/MyProfilePage.page)

Comment: Did you click the "Where is this used" button?

Comment: The code shows that it was for a customer Portal - so would be used in SF portal or community to display the user's profile to them.

Comment: Interesting.. I clicked "Where is this used" button.(Thanks Martin) Its not showing empty. I am checking on portal and sites. lets see. Thanks Dave